# Distribute lists (equally) separated by a character

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I would like to add a paragraph to my document containing names separated by bullet points. Since the names are in different lengths the distribution is not balanced on every line.

When I set the text alignment to justified, the spacing gets too unbalanced. Is illustrator (or something else) able to automatically compute the best alignment for a given list (without hyphenation)? This can of course be unordered.

From a list of word groups:

- Lorem ipsum
- dolor sit amet
- consectetuer adipiscing elit
- **sed diam**
- **nonummy nibh**
- euismod tincidunt
- ut laoreet dolore
- quam erat volutpat
- Ut wisi enim ad
- minim veniam
- tation ullamcorper suscipit
- lobortis nisl ut
- aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
- Duis autem vel eum
- iriure dolor

Something like this:

[image: Example]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's no such functionality in Illustrator, but perhaps you could script it. Might take longer to script than just doing it manually adding spaces to equal out the gaps.